# In Azure, can we connect integration runtimes of ADFs of different account subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, runtime, integration, on-premise2cloud

I have 2 different azure accounts.
In one account I have a ADF and downloaded the Self Hosted IR.
In the other account I have, I need to use IR, but unable to do use even using Linked IR as I am unable to grant permission to this ADF, as it is not visible

I tried to use Managed Identity object Id of the new ADF(to be connected with IR) in the service Identity ID (in the uploaded image) but unable to connect.
I want to know whether ADFs in different account subscriptions can use the same IR on the same machine.

---Update---
Found a way around!

Thanks for the reply, sir.

With different tenants we cannot use the same integration runtime installed on our pc to connect to the ADFs on the different accounts.

I found an alternative solution to get the job done.
We can change the Registration details of the Integration runtime installed on our pc to connect to data factories with different tenants.
This is done by editing the Integration runtime PowerShell configuration file in the Integration runtime folder.

Detailed explanation can be found on the website below.

[Changing Self Hosted Integration Runtime (on pc) registration key](https://www.zachstagers.co.uk/p/changing-a-data-factory-integration-runtime-registration-key/)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by different account? Does it mean different tenants?

Comment: Yes, I meant totally different accounts (different tenants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the aspects w.r.t IR in ADF:

1. You can only host 1 IR mapping to a single ADF on a server
2. IRs can be shared amongst multiple ADFs but they should be in the same tenant.
   You cannot share an IR with ADF mapping to another tenant.
3. In order for you to Share the IR, you need to 1st search the ADF with the one you need to share in the Azure Active directory. So one must have proper read permissions on the Azure AD for sharing/searching purposes